# GPG failing when run by application

Tags: encryption, gnupg

If I run gpg to sign and encrypt a file from the command line, it works.  I have an application that tries the same and I get the following error.  The application has worked signing and encrypting before, so I do not think that it is a permission issue.  Any ideas?

Running on windows.  GnuPG 1.4.2.2

gpg: keyblock resource `C:/Program Files/GNU/GnuPG" --output D:/WEA/ACH/milw472b.gpg --yes --batch --armor --recipient JPMC_ECS_PROD_2015 --default-key wea@weatrust.com --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose --sign --encrypt D:/WEA/ACH/ACH \secring.gpg': file open error
gpg: keyblock resource`C:/Program Files/GNU/GnuPG" --output D:/WEA/ACH/milw472b.gpg --yes --batch --armor --recipient JPMC_ECS_PROD_2015 --default-key wea@weatrust.com --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose --sign --encrypt D:/WEA/ACH/ACH \pubring.gpg': file open error
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: eof

Answer (score 1):

Why is your program including the paths to the public and secret keyrings?  GPG should find them in the home directory, if you're using a different location for those files then you either need to specify the new home directory (with the --homedir flag) or prepend the two keyring files with the relevant flags (--keyring and --secret-keyring).

As it is, that command appears to be trying to encrypt your public and secret keyrings to the "JPMC_ECS_PROD_2015" recipient.  If "JPMC_ECS_PROD_2015" is not a group name (specified in the gpg.conf file) or specified elsewhere in the code for your program, then that will generate errors relating to an invalid recipient (or recipient format).

Comment: In my case the `gpg` command that shipped with `mingw` (via GitHub for Windows) didn't setup the `~/.gnupg` directory. Using `gpg --homedir ~/.gnupg` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, Windows can do some weird things when it comes to designating the homedir. You can always check what it is with `gpg --version` as the homedir location is immediately above the supported algorithms.

Comment: In my case it was set properly (within bash even before installing gpg4win), but it wasn't initiated. Running it with expressly setting it (again?) via `--homedir` did the trick. Ah well. :) Thanks for the help in any case!